# How to exclude URLs from robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I have a lot of URLs in English and Chinese containing documents (content). Both URLs content are same, so I want to disallow Chinese language URLs from `robots.txt`.

Below a snippet of my URLs:

```
   https://www.example.com/zh/docs/UBX-18006379
   https://www.example.com/zh/ubx-viewer/view/cB-2254-12(fw_obs421_rd_v5.3.2).bin
```

Am I right with following wildcard:

```
     1- Disallow: /zh/docs/*
     2- Disallow: /zh/ubx-viewer/*
```

Can anyone please help me? is above is right to use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. Robots does not support regular expressions.

According to https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in
> either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent
> field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot
> have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow:
> *.gif".

But please, remember that `robots.txt` can be ignored by bots. So be aware that anyone can still access those directories if they are publicly available, and you shouldn't store sensitive information in it.
So in your case, if you want to exclude those directories:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /zh/docs/
Disallow: /zh/ubx-viewer/
```